# Firebase errors on page load after Angular upgrade

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, nebular

After upgrading to Angular 13 I'm having issues with auth mechanism. I'm using Nebular Auth over Firebase authentication with Azure. Currently on page load I'm getting this error:

```
zone.js:1063 Unhandled Promise rejection: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.__rest) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.__rest) is not a function
    at new UserImpl (index-342f2197.js:1599:62)
    at Function._fromJSON (index-342f2197.js:1736:22)
    at index-342f2197.js:1865:32
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)
    at zone.js:1276:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1) TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.__rest) is not a function
    at new UserImpl (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:5601:60)
    at Function._fromJSON (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:5831:18)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:6008:30
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184170:24)
    at _next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184192:9)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3497:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3259:43)
    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4401:36
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3531:31)
```

It originates in `firebase-auth.js`. mentioned function is also declared there:

```
function __rest(s, e) {
    var t = {};
    for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p) && e.indexOf(p) < 0)
        t[p] = s[p];
    if (s != null && typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === "function")
        for (var i = 0, p = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(s); i < p.length; i++) {
            if (e.indexOf(p[i]) < 0 && Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(s, p[i]))
                t[p[i]] = s[p[i]];
        }
    return t;
}
```

package.json excerpt:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "^9.0.1",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "9.0.1",
    "@nebular/firebase-auth": "^9.0.1",
    "@nebular/theme": "^9.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
(...)
```

Nebular uses a backward-compatible version of Angular Fire (with compat packages).

Comment: I do not see any issue. But you can try to remvoe `node_module` folder and again, install fresh install using `npm i`

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/tree/master/src/playground/without-layout/firebase here is repo of official code for nebular firebase angular. You can refer it

Comment: @GRD - done that already, as for the nebular - it doesn't seam to me that the problem is there, it's coming from the firebase package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with the unnecessary and incorrect config of typescript. In `tsconfig.json` paths I had this line
`tslib" : ["node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]` and that prevented proper helper resolution from `tslib`. Removal of this setting, which I found is no longer needed resolved the problem.

Comment: So what have you changed then ?

Comment: and this line is not default created by angular ?

Comment: As far as I know not anymore